# Debug Error 438 Excel VBA copy from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

When I run this code, i get the following error"Run-time error'438' : Object doesn't support this property or method" on this line of the code:

'copy the range from source book

wbFrom.Range("A:A").Copy

```
Sub CopyOpenItems()
'
' CopyOpenItems Macro
' Copy open items to sheet.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
'
Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'workbook where the data is to be pasted
Dim wbFrom As Workbook 'workbook from where the data is to be copied
Dim wsFrom As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

'set to the current active workbook (the source book)
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)


'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open("......")
Set wsFrom = wbFrom.Worksheets(1)


'activate the source book
wbFrom.Activate

'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'copy the range from source book
wbFrom.Range("A:A").Copy

'paste the data on the target book
wbTarget.Range("A:A").PasteSpecial

wbFrom.Range("C:C").Copy
wbTarget.Range("C:C").PasteSpecial

wbFrom.Range("D:D").Copy
wbTarget.Range("D:D").PasteSpecial

wbFrom.Range("F:F").Copy
wbTarget.Range("F:F").PasteSpecial

wbFrom.Range("J:J").Copy
wbTarget.Range("J:J").PasteSpecial

wbFrom.Range("K:K").Copy
wbTarget.Range("K:K").PasteSpecial

'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'save the target book
wbTarget.Save
wbFrom.Save


'close the workbook
wbFrom.Close

'activate the source book again
wbFrom.Activate


'clear memory
Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbFrom = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. The point of the code i guess is pretty straightforward, copy selected columns from one workbook and paste it into another.
Also, this code is a slightly modified version of the one that could be find on this link
https://ccm.net/faq/24666-copy-data-to-another-workbook-in-excel

Comment: A `Workbook` doesn't have a `Range` property, but a `Worksheet` does - `wsFrom` instead of `wbFrom`. Same goes for `wsTarget` instead of `wbTarget`.

Comment: That linked code is wrong.

Comment: It worked thank you

Comment: And this makes an extremely good argument *against* [Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) prefixes such as `wb` and `ws`, which obviously failed their purpose here. cc @BigBen

Comment: @MathieuGuindon completely agree.